# val_loss: 1.1921e-07 - val_acc: 0.0715 How is that possible?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am currently training this model: https://pastebin.com/F7dQvmZP. When i trained it with only 1 feature (raw data) per timestep i got a loss of ~1.3 and an accuracy of ~57%. After adding the direction of change (1 if increased 0 if same -1 if decreased) as a second feature to each timestep my loss went down to ~0.8 and my accuracy increased to ~70%. Then i added a differently scaled version of the raw data as a third feature. This data is basically scaled such that the maximum reading during that timeseries is 1.0. Training this quickly results in a loss of ~1e-7 but the accuracy stays at ~7%. The input is composed like this

```
np.dstack((measurements, change, scaled))
```

I dont really know how that is possible since my outputs are one hot encoded and I only have 22 classes. The training data includes 291300 training and 97100 validation samples. It trains normal until I add the third feature (Even if I only use the third feature). Any help would be appreciated.